# PhpMyAdmin security warning for configuration files

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'.

I got this when I opened up phpmyadmin ...

Any way to fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with the way to fix this that is described in the text?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just a warning to show that there is no password for the default user root. If you want to set password for root:

1. Open phpmyadmin interface
2. Click "Users" tab
3. Select user "root"
4. Edit Privileges
5. Change password

Comment: thats done !!! but after that this comes...Error

MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Restart your mysql server. Which OS is yours ??

Comment: WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM

Comment: t when open mysql console and enter the password , i cant get login window in phpmyadmin . directly login into

Comment: I can't get you what is the error

Comment: from one link i got that you have to write [mysqld]
skip-grant-tables into mysql.ini file and i have done this .. due to this i got directly to the phpmyadmin window no login window..if i remove this line from the mysql.ini then it throws error as i said earlier what to do ????

Comment: Can you go to the folder of phpmyadmin and then open config.inc.php file and in that set $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false

Comment: Similarly to what @Sabari mentioned, If you see an error after setting the user's password, go to `wamp/apps/phpmyadminx/config.inc.php` and update `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password_here'`

Answer (score 5):

Sure, set up a password for user `root`.

You can do that two ways, using the console and typing something like:

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Or you can go through phpMyAdmin interface, go to users, select root and change it's password.

Answer (score 2):

The message simply warns you that you are using the default MySQL user (username `root` with no password) to get complete acces to MySQL server.

Just change your MySQL server `root` password and edit your PhpMyAdmin configuration to include the new password.

If you get this on a local machine not accessible from outside (i.e. your personal local development server), you should not worry about that.