# Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) error in easy php

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, privileges, easyphp

using easy php. After installing the easy php, that shows "Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'." (For other details see the image and the error at bottom of the image)[image]

By this error i am not able to insert values in database

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhpMyAdmin security warning for configuration files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054374/phpmyadmin-security-warning-for-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-----> change the port number in mysql file [ right click easyphp and go to config files you can find it];
       search 3306 and change it to 8088
2----->access denied error
    goto C:\Users\something\Documents\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\modules\phpmyadmin414x140419170848 open config.inc.php file
      change the password to 12345 [ you mysql server password username root]

3------>
     can't create your table
     goto C:\Users\something\Documents\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\modules\phpmyadmin414x140419170848\examples open create_table.sql
    import sql file to your easyphp and press go ..

finally you can do anything on php